# Set default value for argument of type Vec<String> using Clap 4 Rust

Tags: rust, clap

In Clap 2, the following:

```rust
.arg(
   Arg::with_name("files")
   .value_name("FILE")
   .help("Input file(s)")
   .multiple(true)
   .default_value("-"),
)
```

will produce:

```bash
USAGE:
    catr [FLAGS] [FILE]...

FLAGS:
    -h, --help               Prints help information
```

I want to express this in Clap 4 using the `derive` API.

So, I've got the struct:

```rust
pub struct Config{ // Define a public struct called Config.
    /// The input files
    #[arg(default_value_t= vec!["-".to_string()])]
    files: Vec<String>,
```

When I `cargo build`, I get the following:

```bash
[ 19:37:42 ] ❯ cargo build
   Compiling catr v0.1.0 (/home/david/Work/Bitbucket/OReilly/Books/cmdlinerust/ch03/catr)
error[E0277]: `Vec<std::string::String>` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/lib.rs:10:11
   |
10 |     #[arg(default_value_t=vec!["-".to_string()])]
   |           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Vec<std::string::String>` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `Vec<std::string::String>`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
   = note: required for `Vec<std::string::String>` to implement `ToString`
```

As a Rust beginner, I understand that `Vec<String>` doesn't implement the `Display` trait but I don't think I can do that for `Vec<String>`.

Anyway, the question is how do I translate the code in Clap 2 to Clap 4 (I believe that because I have `Vec<String>` I don't have to explicitly specify the `multiple part)?

Comment: One solution would be to wrap `Vec<String>` into a newtype and implement `Display` on that, but there might be a better solution with `clap` support

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues. That sounds like a good exercise to learn `trait` implementation. I'll sure give that a go.

Comment: @Finomnis: This indeed did it. Now if only, I knew how to promote your comment to be the answer...

Comment: @DavidS the way to promote a comment to an answer is to use the big box below and write an answer. You should credit Finomnis and expand a little on the comment though.

Comment: I'll write an answer.

Comment: Your edit fixed the code. You should revert the third code block so that the code matches the error message.

Comment: Actually, your real error is that you mistyped `default_value_t` instead of `default_values_t`. Will vote to close due to a typo. It [works with `default_values_t`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bcdb4807773b09bab55b9b4a5fc06c80).

Comment: Also, this demonstrates the importance of providing a [MRE]. Please provide one next time, not just a small code snippet without context. This most likely would have answered your question in the process of writing it here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution is a single letter: `default_values_t` instead of `default_value_t`.

```rs
#[arg(default_values_t = ["-".to_string()])]
```

You also don't need `vec!` because it takes `IntoIterator<Item = String>`.

Comment: He already typed that. He didn't write `default_value_t`.

Comment: Actually, I take that back, his question is inconsistent. There is `default_value_t` in his error message. I apologize. Although that means we should close this question as a typo.

Comment: I think it's fine, without the "s" is a valid attribute, just not the right one. Also the question's edit is what introduced the inconsistency.

Comment: Yes, if he would have written `default_value_t` everywhere. But as his question is inconsistent, It's a mix of "there is no error" and "it's a typo".

Comment: Apologies all round for having the wrong code in the question. It's now been corrected.

Comment: It looks like `default_values=[...]` works as well and is a bit more flexible, as it only requires a `impl IntoIterator<Item = impl Into<OsStr>>`, not a... `Into<Vec<String>>`?. So you can pass the simpler `["-"]`. Also provides a handy, concise way to say that the default is the empty vector: `default_values=[""; 0]`.